# Number of ways to get 3 groups of 5 people each

Tags: probability, combinatorics

i have been thinking about this problem and cant get the answer.

Can you please help me solve it?

There are 22 people and we have to make 3 groups (Financial, advertising and legal) of 5 people each.

in how many ways is this possible?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first group pick 5 people out the 22 available in $$\binom{22}{5}$$ possible ways. Now, of the remaining $22-5=17$, take another 5 in $$\binom{17}{5}$$ ways. And finally pick 5 more out of the remaining 12: $$\binom{12}{5}$$ Multiplying these three quantities gives the answer, which will be a very large number. My calculator says it is $$129060195264$$